# Burning Centos DVD with BitTorrent delivery

Tags: linux, centos

I elected to use the BitTorrent delivery method for downloading Centos 5.  Instead of getting a single .iso file, I get 8 pieces with 8 sumcheck files.

What do I do with these files?  Do I use 'cat' to assemble them into a single ISO file???

Also, the files is assembled, can it be used as an installation media for VirtualBox without burning a DVD.

Answer (score 1):

If you got 8 files, then you downloaded the Centos 8 CD torrent. You probably wanted the DVD torrent. But since you are installing in VirtualBox, you should be able to [mount up those eight files as 8 CDs and install from there](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-storage).